# Geodesic Dome of Hexagons

Tags: geometry, geodesic

I am trying figure out the minimum size of a world that is made of hexagonal tiles for it to be not very noticeable. I cannot find anything online that is directly helping me; so I come here. In my model, every hexagon is 10 meters in diameter.

[image]

Make a geodesic sphere with only hexagons.

[image: The geodesic sphere]

- What is the minimum number of hexagons to produce this?
- What is the minimum number of hexagons I need to add to make the geodesic sphere larger?
- How do I calculate the angle of declination given the number of hexagons in a geodesic sphere?

There are the questions I have come up with. Let me know if they need to be on their own question, but they are all closely related to each-other.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you look closely enough at the image you linked, you will notice several pentagons :-)
In fact, it is not possible to build a sphere using only regular hexagons.

Comment: nooooooooooooooo!

Comment: ill look into triangles.

Comment: Yes, you need pentagons, 12 of them, or smaller numbers of squares or triangles.  But try using hexagons to tile a _torus_.

Comment: That is an interesting proposal, a toroidal world.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to model a spherical board game.  Unfortunately, as already stated, pentagons are required, so that will complicate the game's auto-logic for a very few pentagonal tiles among the hugely more numerous hexagonal tiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "ill look into triangles"

---

[image: GeoDome]

---

Comment: Is each triangle in this the same size?

Comment: @Tsangares: Nearly but not precisely. It is not possible to tile the sphere with many equilateral triangles. This is about as close as is achievable.